# Instantiate Identity ApplicationUserManager in Class Library

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity-2, asp.net-mvc-5

One of the things I do not like about Identity is that the UserManagers have to be instantiated in the controller that you wish to get user information for.  In my project, I moved all the business logic into a DAL class library and wanted the Identity to be there as well.

I have already moved all the identity classes into the DAL class library (ApplicationRole, ApplicationUser, ApplicationRoleManager, ApplicationSignInManager, ApplicationUserManager, EmailSerivce, SmsService)

My DataContext inherits from IdentityDBContext

```
public class DataContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DataContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false) 
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }

    public static DataContext Create()
    {
        return new DataContext();
    }

    static DataContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<DataContext, DataContextMigrationsConfiguration>());   
    }
```

So I have access to user and roles via the DB context

```
internal class UserRepository
{
    internal ApplicationUser GetUserById(string id)
    {
        using(var db = new DataContext())
        {
            return db.Users.Where(a => a.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();

        }
    }
}
```

The problem is I do not have access to methods that the ApplicationUserManager exposes.  I am trying to Access the ApplicationUserManager from within my user repository but do not know how to instantiate the ApplciationUserManager class.

In the controllers, its instantiated as follows

```
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }
```

However, in the repository in the DAL class library, I do not have access to the OwinContext to get the user manager.

How can I access the ApplicationUserManager from within a Class Library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Visual studio's default MVC template is using the below code to create the **ApplicationUserManager** instance.

```
var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
```

It might be possible to instantiate it in your class library if you can provide it with the **ApplicationDbContext (DataContext in your case)** instance which is being retrieved from **OwinContext**

e.g.

```
var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new DataContext()));
```

and also you might have to find some alternatives to instantiate **ApplicationUserManager** class properties like **UserValidator**, **PasswordValidator** etc.

I hope this could give you some idea to proceed!

Comment: This is perfect. Exactly what i needed! Thanks!

Comment: Good to hear that. *Please consider marking the answer if it addresses your question*

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Sivaram K this is how i was able to access the Application Manager.

```
internal ApplicationUser GetUserById(string id)
    {
        using(var db = new DataContext())
        {
            var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db));

        }

        using(var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new DataContext())))
        {

        }
    }
```