# Using MVC Identity code from desktop application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin

I'm trying to use the MVC Identity code from a desktop application. The desktop application needs to make a bunch of additions and updates to my user data.

I have copied the classes over from a generated MVC application, installed the required packages and made all changes necessary for the code to compile.

The only problem I have now is creating an instance of the `ApplicationUserManager` class.

```
public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
{
    get => _userManager ?? HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    private set
    {
        _userManager = value;
    }
}
private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
```

The problem is I have no `HttpContext`, and so `HttpContext.Current` will always return null.

Is what I'm doing possible? How can I build a `UserManager` from a desktop application without an HTTP context?

**UPDATE:**

I have direct access to the database, so I'd be happy with a solution that didn't require the Identity code and classes. The biggest hurdle here would be creating and updating passwords so that they can be "understood" by the Identity code in my website app.

Comment: Judging by your update, you are looking for [PasswordHasher](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/bfec2c14be1e65f7dd361a43950d4c848ad0cd35/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/PasswordHasher.cs#L17) class. This will allow you to compare passwords and hash new ones for users. However, `UserManager` class will generally give you a lot of the functionality without dipping into `HttpContext`

Comment: @trailmax: That looks interesting but it appears it supports multiple hashing versions. I'll look some more but so far haven't found clear documentation of which one(s) will work with the MVC Identity code.

Comment: You've already got some answers, but this looks to be essentially the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42556258/instantiate-identity-applicationusermanager-in-class-library/42556847

Comment: @JonathanWood Have you considered just exposing the desired functionality as a web API that is called from the desktop application?

Comment: @Nkosi: No, and it's an interesting thought. But I need to update hundreds of records and test if each one already exists. So this wouldn't be the most efficient approach. And the web API would need to be pulled after the work is done.

Comment: My generated code doesn't use HttpContext.Current but an IOwinContext (which kinds of answer the question). Could you detail the steps you use?

Comment: @JonathanWood The different versions are simple cut here: if your MVC is version 5, then you need Identity2 and [hashing from there](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/blob/4874623fb8cdaeeded92891af5017d8480fd014a/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/PasswordHasher.cs#L4). If you are on Asp.Net Core, then my first link will do the job. Though the first link should work with both versions of password hashes.

Answer (score 7):

interesting approach,

otherwise, it will be necessary to clean out everything that httpcontext touches..

you can create ApplicationUserManager instance like this.

```
public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
{
    get
    { 
        if(_userManager == null)
        {
            _userManager =  new ApplicationUserManager(new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore<ApplicationUser>(yourDbContext));
        }
        return _userManager;
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider using [`Lazy<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1) for [Lazy Initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/performance/lazy-initialization). It'll save lots of headache if you need thread safety.

Comment: This appears to be the most direct answer to the question asked. However, using this approach, the `DbContext` must include data models for the required tables. Mine didn't. In the end, it looks like I'll be following @trailmax's suggestion by just accessing the database directly and using the `PasswordHasher` to add and update password hashes. I still have a few details to work through, but so far this seems to be working best for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

```
var context = ApplicationDbContext.Create();
var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);
//change password
var result = userManager.ChangePasswordAsync("userId", "oldPwd", "newPwd");
```

Comment: Thanks. However, this seems to duplicate levent's answer.